# a server client application using TCP in C in linux environment,

Tags: c, linux, algorithm, tcp, cryptography

i have created a server client application using TCP in C in linux environment,and it is working very well.
I wish to improve the application by including a cryptographic algorithm into it so that the server just gets to know about who has logged in and out of the server but not about the information shared between the clients.
Any suggestions for algorithm that i should employ in my project to achieve the desired result.
I am currently looking into MD5 algorithm.

Comment: If it's for a real world application I suggest a transposition cipher

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you want to encrypt/decrypt messages between users. If so MD5 won't do it as it is just a hash function.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Probably the best algorithm to do so would be AES:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

There are many implementation (including in C) on the web so you can literally copy-paste the code (mind the license ;) ).